# Replace parts of string formula with relevant values

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table (`tbl_Composites`) which contains formulas that are used to calculate performance scores. e.g.

```
     KPI       |           FORMULA                | 
--------------------------------------------------
Productivity   |  [ItemsCompleted]/[LoggedInTime] | 
SalesConversion|  [Sales]+[Leads]/[TotalCalls]    |
```

There is another table (`tbl_BaseData`) which has a column which contains these metrics and the associated value for each person

```
 SCOREDATE | USERID  |    METRIC       | VALUE | 
------------------------------------------------
01/03/2017 | 20511   | ItemsCompleted  |  50   | 
01/03/2017 | 20511   | LoggedInTime    |  320  | 
01/03/2017 | 20630   | Sales           |  8    | 
01/03/2017 | 20630   | Leads           |  3    | 
01/03/2017 | 20630   | TotalCalls      |  25   |
```

I am trying to write a VBA function that will take the parameters of the Date, UserID and the KPI and then get the relevant metric values for that KPI formula and calculate the result.

I have something I've managed to put together but it's not very efficient and it doesn't work if there is no record for one of the metrics (e.g someone took calls but made no sales).

```vba
Function CalulateFormula(strFormula As String, userID As String, scoreDate As Date) As String
Dim Metric As String, valueList As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Len(strFormula)
    If Mid(strFormula, i, 1) = "[" Then
        Metric = Mid(strFormula, i + 1, InStr(i + 1, strFormula, "]") - i - 1)
        valueList = valueList & "'" & Metric & "', "
        CalulateFormula = CalulateFormula & Metric
        i = InStr(i + 1, strFormula, "]")
    Else
        CalulateFormula = CalulateFormula & Mid(strFormula, i, 1)
    End If
Next i

valueList = Left(valueList, Len(valueList) - 2)

CalulateFormula = EvaluateSQL(CalulateFormula, valueList, userID, scoreDate)

End Function
```

This will build the formula string and populate a list of the metrics that it will need to find. It then calls another function as below, which runs some SQL to get the metric values and evaluate the formula.

```vba
Function EvaluateSQL(CalulateFormula As String, valueList As String, userID     As String, scoreDate As Date) As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    strSQL = "SELECT Metric, metricValue " & _
         "FROM tbl_BaseData " & _
         "WHERE metric in (" & valueList & ") AND userID = '" & userID & "' AND     scoreDate = #" & Format(scoreDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# "

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Do Until rs.EOF
    CalulateFormula = Replace(CalulateFormula, rs!Metric, rs!metricValue)
rs.MoveNext
Loop
EvaluateSQL = Eval(CalulateFormula)
End Function
```

This seems like quite a roundabout way of doing things and I'm wondering if I need to approach the problem from a completely different angle. Could anyone advise me if there is a simpler / more efficient way that will also be able to handle null / missing values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're over-thinking your string generation.  Your values for `FORMULA` already contain the calculation operation `/`, so you can read the full value of `FORMULA` as your SQL calculation.  It looks like a lot of your concern is with the brackets in your `FORMULA` values, but SQL will read `[ItemsCompleted]` as a valid field name for a calculation.

Better than the above, you can do this entirely in SQL code.

What you really need here is a single line per user per day.  With that, you can easily run your metrics; you don't even need the `tbl_Composites` table.

So here's how you do it:

```
SELECT
    SCOREDATE
    ,USERID
    ,ItemsCompleted / LoggedInTime as Productivity
    ,Sales + Leads as SalesConversion
    from
    (SELECT distinct 
        base.SCOREDATE, 
        base.USERID, 
        ic.ItemsCompleted,
        lt.LoggedInTime,
        sls.Sales,
        lds.Leads,
        tc.TotalCalls
    from (((((
    tbl_BaseData as base
        left join
            (SELECT SCOREDATE, USERID, VALUE as ItemsCompleted
            from tbl_BaseData
            where METRIC = 'ItemsCompleted') as ic
            on base.USERID = ic.USERID
                and base.SCOREDATE = ic.SCOREDATE)
        left join
            (SELECT SCOREDATE, USERID, VALUE as LoggedInTime
            from tbl_BaseData
            where METRIC = 'LoggedInTime') as lt
            on base.USERID = lt.USERID
                and base.SCOREDATE = lt.SCOREDATE)
        left join
            (SELECT SCOREDATE, USERID, VALUE as Sales
            from tbl_BaseData
            where METRIC = 'Sales') as sls
            on base.USERID = sls.USERID
                and base.SCOREDATE = sls.SCOREDATE)
        left join
            (SELECT SCOREDATE, USERID, VALUE as Leads
            from tbl_BaseData
            where METRIC = 'Leads') as lds
            on base.USERID = lds.USERID
                and base.SCOREDATE = lds.SCOREDATE)
        left join
            (SELECT SCOREDATE, USERID, VALUE as TotalCalls
            from tbl_BaseData
            where METRIC = 'TotalCalls') as tc
            on base.USERID = tc.USERID
                and base.SCOREDATE = tc.SCOREDATE))
        as p
```

The inner query does the work of consolidating your data to one line per User, and accounts for nonexistent record types.  Alone, it returns:

```
SCOREDATE   USERID  ItemsCompleted   LoggedInTime  Sales  Leads   TotalCalls
01/03/2017  20511   50               320           NULL   NULL    NULL
01/03/2017  20630   NULL             NULL          8      3       25
```

The outer query then calculates Productivity and SalesConversion.  You can add lines for whatever other metric you need.  It returns:

```
SCOREDATE   USERID    Productivity    SalesConversion
01/03/2017  20511     0.156           NULL
01/03/2017  20630     NULL            11
```

Comment: Hi Rominus. Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure how I can enter the formula directly into an sql calculation as the parts of the formula are not fields, they are values held in the [metric] field. Could you give an example of what you mean? Also, I put the parts of the formula in square brackets so the function I wrote would know where they start and stop but I'm definitely open to changing it if there's a better way

Comment: The more I look at this the more I think your table structure is the root cause of this complexity.  You mentioned you have problems if there's no record of a particular type; could you create a record with the value of zero instead of not creating a record?  That would make more sense for record keeping anyway, IMO.

Comment: Ok, redid this entirely in SQL, and it works with nonexistent records

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect such a comprehensive answer. Thank you so much for the time you spent on this. Unfortunately I have tried to run this SQL query and I'm getting an error message saying **Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in Query Expression ''** I'm trying to understand it to see if I can figure out which part it doesn't like but I'm not sure why it isn't working

Comment: Aha! It was just that Access requires you to bracket the nested joins. I've edited your answer and it works perfectly now. Thank you so much for this, I have a solution to my problem and I've also learnt something. I really appreciate your help!